# Помогите пожалуйста: ошибки линкера LNK2001

Tags: visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define PORT 80
#define SERVERADDR "93.184.216.119"

int main()
{
    char buff[1024];
    std::cout << "hi karo4" << std::endl;

    // Шаг 1 - инициализация библиотеки Winsock
    WSAStartup(0x202, (WSADATA *)&buff[0]);

    // Шаг 2 - создание сокета
    SOCKET my_sock;
    my_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Шаг 3 - установка соединения
    // заполнение структуры sockaddr_in - указание адреса и порта сервера
    sockaddr_in dest_addr;
    dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    HOSTENT *hst;

    // преобразование IP адреса из символьного в сетевой формат
    if (inet_addr(SERVERADDR) != INADDR_NONE)
        dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(SERVERADDR);
    else
    {
        // попытка получить IP адрес по доменному имени сервера
        if (hst = gethostbyname(SERVERADDR))
            // hst->h_addr_list содержит не массив адресов,
            // а массив указателей на адреса
            ((unsigned long *)&dest_addr.sin_addr)[0] =
            ((unsigned long **)hst->h_addr_list)[0][0];
        else
        {
            std::cout << SERVERADDR << std::endl;
            closesocket(my_sock);
            WSACleanup();
            return -1;
        }
    }

    // адрес сервера получен - пытаемся установить соединение
    if (connect(my_sock, (sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr)))
    {
       std::cout << WSAGetLastError()<< std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "Соединение  успешно установлено " << SERVERADDR << std::endl;

    // Шаг 4 - чтение и передача сообщений
    int nsize;
    while ((nsize = recv(my_sock, &buff[0], sizeof(buff) - 1, 0)) != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        // ставим завершающий ноль в конце строки
        buff[nsize] = 0;

        // выводим на экран
        std::cout << buff;

    }
    closesocket(my_sock);
            WSACleanup();
          return 0;
}
```

Ошибки:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__recv@16 в функции _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__WSAGetLastError@0 в функции _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__connect@12 в функции _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__WSACleanup@0 в функции _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__closesocket@4 в функции _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__gethostbyname@4 в функции _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__inet_addr@4 в функции _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__htons@4 в функции _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__socket@12 в функции _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__WSAStartup@8 в функции _main
1>C:\Users\Admin\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ololo2\Debug\ololo2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 10 неразрешенных внешних элементов
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте пятой-шестой строкой

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```